# How to set a default page for load first time?

Tags: pages, homepage

Now I am creating a WordPress site for an academy. But my client has more than one site. So I need to set a home page that contains choose site option at first time. Simply I need to set a home page which contains some site's link. Eg: When user  enter into my site first time need to show a welcome page for the user.

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried?

Comment: You will have to figure out what "first" means. There is no way I can think of to determine "first visit" in any absolute sense.

Comment: @s_ha_dum First means first time only.. Just like a welcome page.

Comment: And that is exactly the absolute sense that isn't possible by any means I know. First visit? First by what criteria? IP? IPs are shared by numerous people, typically. Check for a cookie? Cookies can be deleted. Logged in vs not logged in? Registered vs not registered? What is an acceptable criteria? "First" by normal standards won't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins for what you need.

Give it a try: [Wp Splash Page](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-splash-page/)

Comment: But it shows only popup div not a page.

Comment: Updated the link.

Answer (score -2):

in  admin side

setting->reading-> [image]

select your page or post u want to display.

Comment: When I am set it as a home page which act as home_url(); I don't want it. I need to display a welcome page at first time only.

Comment: You got the question wrong